# User removing a "Friend" is deleting the user object

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, postgresql, ruby-on-rails-5

I have a feature where you may add others to be your friend and then when they're your friend, an ability to delte them.

View:

```
<a href="+user_friend_path(current_user,user)+" data-confirm='Do you want to remove #{user.profile.first_name} from your Friends?'></a>
```

User Model:

```
has_many :friendships, dependent: :destroy
has_many :friends, through: :friendships

 def remove_friend(friend)
    self.friends.destroy(friend)
 end
```

Friendships Model

```
after_destroy :destroy_inverse_relationship

belongs_to :user
belongs_to :friend, class_name: 'User'
```

Friends Controller

```
def destroy
    item = current_user.remove_friend(@friend)
    redirect_to user_path(@friend), notice: "#{@friend.profile.first_name} was removed from your friends"
  end
```

Routes:

```
resources :users do
   resources :friends, only: [:index, :destroy]
end
```

**How it works:**

1) You would click to remove

2) Goes to friendship controller

3) Grabs current user, and calls `remove_friend` on the Users model

4) Relational should destroy friendship

**What is Happening:** It is destroying and deleting the actual user

**What Should Happen:** Delete row in `friendships` table

Comment: Why don't you just delete the friendship? `friendships.where(friend: friend).delete_all`

Comment: I've that that but then in the Friendship the "destroy_inverse_relationship" is called and deletes the User

Comment: what does `destroy_inverse_relationship` do?

Answer (score 2):

I suspect your problem is here:

```
def remove_friend(friend)
  self.friends.destroy(friend)
end
```

I don't know what it is you think you're doing there, but it looks fishy to me.

Instead, try:

```
def remove_friend(friend)
  friendships.where(friend: friend).destroy_all
end
```

If you don't want to instantiate the `friendships` records and/or trigger any callbacks you can do (see the [docs](https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Relation.html#method-i-delete_all)):

```
def remove_friend(friend)
  friendships.where(friend: friend).delete_all
end
```

BTW, why aren't you using a `link_to` helper, here:

```
<a href="+user_friend_path(current_user,user)+" data-confirm='Do you want to remove #{user.profile.first_name} from your Friends?'></a>
```

Handcrafting HTML like that seems like not the best idea. In fact, I am surprised that link even works. But, maybe it does.

Comment: It still does not work. The method is somehow calling the destroy function on the users controller. I've added my routes file and also a line in the Friendship model. (Added Above).

Comment: Could you please show: (1) your link HTML as rendered in the browser, (2) the problem transaction trace from your console/server.